# Best way to partition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Considering a table like this

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30/07/2022 |
| 1 | 29/07/2022 |
| 1 | 28/07/2022 |
| 2 | 15/07/2022 |
| 3 | 15/07/2022 |
| 3 | 14/07/2022 |

How do you write a linq query to get this result? (in one query of course, and without any loop)

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30/07/2022 |
| 2 | 15/07/2022 |
| 3 | 15/07/2022 |

Or to specify it clearly, the closest date by Id

It's easy to write this in SQL but I can't find a satisfying way to do it in LINQ

Comment: [DistinctBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinctby?view=net-6.0), ordering it first

Comment: Which ORM, which version?

Comment: It doesn't matter, anything Queryable

Comment: I DOES matter, that's why I ask.

Comment: If you think so... your favorite then, if you have any answer for any ORM, any version, feel free to provide it.

Comment: *"the closest date by Id"* -- What does "closest" means in this context?

Comment: I removed the linq-to-sql tag because, as said, it really does matter which ORM you use. L2S is the least likely one nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
var result = table
    .GroupBy(t => t.Id)
    .Select(t => new { Id = t.Key, Date = t.Max(o => o.Date)})
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thera are the ways that I know, if you need all fields from table, not just Date.

EF 6 and EF Core 6 +

```cs
var query = 
    from c in db.Some
    group c by new { c.Id } into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Date).First();
```

Other versions and probaly other providers

```cs
// make common variable because it may be query with filter
var data = db.Some;

var query = 
    from d in data.Select(d => new { d.Id }).Distinct()
    from c in data
        .Where(c => c.Id == d.Id)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.Date)
        .Take(1)
    select c;
```

Fastest variant via [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db)

```cs
var query = 
    from c in db.Some
    select new 
    {
        c,
        RN = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over()
            .PartitionBy(c.Id)
            .OrderByDesc(c.Date)
            .ToValue()
    } into s
    where s.RN == 1
    select s.c;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you return only the First record which doesn't solve my issue (unless I create a loop which is specifically the thing I don't want to do)

Comment: Which issue is not solved? LINQ query returns First record of each group - exactly what you need. Probably you have copied code in wrong way.